# Writing decorator for pytest test method

Tags: python, decorator, pytest

Assuming the following structure:

```
class SetupTestParam(object):
    def setup_method(self, method):
        self.foo = bar()

    @pytest.fixture
    def some_fixture():
        self.baz = 'foobar'
```

I use `SetupTestParam` as a parent class for test classes.

```
class TestSomething(SetupTestParam):
    def test_a_lot(self, some_fixture):
        with self.baz as magic:
            with magic.fooz as more_magic:
                 blah = more_magic.much_more_magic() # repetative bleh
            ... # not repetative code here
            assert spam == 'something cool'
```

Now, writing tests gets repetitive (with statement usage) and I would like to write a decorator to reduce the number of code lines. But there is a problem with pytest and the function signature.

I found out [library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) which should be helpful but I can't manage to get it to work.

I made a `classmethod` in my `SetupTestParam` class.

```
@classmethod
@decorator.decorator
def this_is_decorator(cls, f):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        with self.baz as magic:
            with magic.fooz as more_magic:
                 blah = more_magic.much_more_magic() # repetative bleh
            return f(self, *args)
    return wrapper
```

After I decorate the `test_a_lot` method, I receive the error `TypeError: transaction_decorator() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Can someone explain me please what am I doing wrong? (I assume there is a problem with `self` from the test method?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some tweaking and realizing that I need to pass a parameter to decorator I choosed to write it as a class:

```
class ThisIsDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param   # Parameter may vary with the function being decorated
    def __call__(self, fn):
        wraps(fn) # [1]
        def wrapper(fn, fn_self, *args): # [2] fn_self refers to original self param from function fn (test_a_lot) [2]
            with fn_self.baz as fn_self.magic: # I pass magic to fn_self to make magic accesible in function fn (test_a_lot)
                with fn_self.magic.fooz as more_magic:
                    blah = self.param.much_more_magic() # repetative bleh
            return fn(fn_self, *args)
        return decorator.decorator(wrapper, fn)
```

[1] I use `wraps` to have original `fn` `__name__`, `__module__` and `__doc__`.

[2] Params passed to  `wrapper` were `self = <function test_a_lot at 0x24820c8> args = (<TestSomething object at 0x29c77d0>, None, None, None, None), kw = {}` so I took out the `args[0]` as a `fn_self`.

Original version (without passing a parameter):

```
 @classmethod
 def this_is_decorator(cls, fn):
     @wraps(fn)
     def wrapper(fn, fn_self, *args):
         with fn_self.baz as fn_self.magic:
             with fn_self.magic.fooz as more_magic:
                 blah = more_magic.much_more_magic() # repetative bleh
             return fn(fn_self, *args)
     return decorator.decorator(wrapper,fn)
```

Thanks go to Mike Muller for pointing out the right direction.

Comment: If Mike's answer helped, it's usually nice to upvote it... :)

Answer (score 4):

Chaining decorators is not the simplest thing to do. One solution might be to separate the two decorators. Keep the `classmethod` but move `decorator.decorator` to the end:

```
@classmethod
def this_is_decorator(cls, f):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        with self.baz as magic:
            with magic.fooz as more_magic:
                 blah = more_magic.much_more_magic() # repetative bleh
            return f(self, *args)
    return decorator.decorator(wrapper, f)
```

Maybe this works for you.

Comment: And how can I access self.foo from SetupTestParam in the wrapper function?

Comment: Yes. I figured out a rest also. Here are wrapper parameters as shown in pytest:
`self = <function test_a_lot at 0x24820c8>
args = (<TestSomething object at 0x29c77d0>, None, None, None, None), kw = {}` 
So it is not `self.baz` but `args[0].baz` now. And I have to return just `f(*args)`.

Comment: Great. Maybe you can answer your own question putting all the pieces in the answers and the comments together. Answering own questions is encouraged:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to

Comment: Yes, I will do that as soon as I finish tweaking my decorator. Using `args[0]` looks terrible. Is there any way how to ommit passing instance of the function (`self` parameter in this case) to `wrapper` ? I would like to see `self` of `wrapper` to be reference of `self` of `test_a_lot`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens in time order as this method is defined.

1. `this_is_decorator` is created (not called).
2. `decorator.decorator(this_is_decorator)` is called.  This returns a new function which becomes `this_is_decorator` and has the same usage.
3. `classmethod(this_is_decorator)` is called, and the result of that is a classmethod that accepts `(cls, f)` and returns `wrapper`.
4. Later at runtime, a call to `this_is_decorator` will return `wrapper`.

But considering that `this_is_decorator` is a class method, it's not clear to me that this is what you want.  I'm guessing that you may want something more like this:

```
from decorator import decorator
@decorator
def mydecorator(f):
  def wrapper(cls, *args, **kw):
    # ... logging, reporting, caching, whatever
    return f(*args, **kw)
  return wrapper

class MyClass(object):
  @classmethod
  @mydecorator
  def myclsmethod(a, b, c):
    # no cls or self value accepted here; this is a function not a method
    # ...
```

Here your decorator is defined outside your class, because it's changing an ordinary function into a `classmethod` (and because you may want to use it in other places).  The order of execution here is:

1. `mydecorator` is defined, not called.
2. `decorator(mydecorator)` is called, and the result *becomes* `mydecorator`.
3. Creation of `MyClass` starts.
4. `myclsmethod` is created.  It is an ordinary function, not a method.  There is a difference within the VM, so that you do not have to explicitly supply `cls` or `self` arguments to methods.
5. `myclsmethod` is passed to `mydecorator` (which has itself been decorated before) and the result (`wrapper`) is *still a function not a method*.
6. The result of `mydecorator` is passed to `classmethod` which returns an actual class method that is bound to `MyClass.myclsmethod`.
7. Definition of `MyClass` finishes.
8. Later when `MyClass.myclsmethod(a, b, c)` is called, `wrapper` executes, which then calls the original `myclsmethod(a, b, c)` function (which it knows as `f`) without supplying the `cls` argument.

Since you have an additional need to preserve the argument list exactly, so that even the names of the arguments are preserved in the decorated function, except with an extra initial argument `cls`, then you could implement `mydecorator` this way:

```
from decorator import decorator
from inspect import getargspec

@decorator
def mydecorator(func):
  result = [None]  # necessary so exec can "return" objects
  namespace = {'f': func, 'result': result}
  source = []
  add = lambda indent, line: source.append(' ' * indent + line)  # shorthand
  arglist = ', '.join(getargspec(func).args)  # this does not cover keyword or default args
  add(0, 'def wrapper(cls, %s):' % (arglist,))
  add(2, 'return f(%s)' % (arglist,))
  add(0, 'result[0] = wrapper')  # this is how to "return" something from exec
  exec '\n'.join(source) in namespace
  return result[0]  # this is wrapper
```

It's kinda ugly, but this is the only way I know to dynamically set the argument list of a function based on data.  If returning a `lambda` is OK, you could use `eval` instead of `exec`, which eliminates the need for an array that gets written into but is otherwise about the same.

Comment: I use `classmethod` to decorate `this_is_decorator` because I want to use this decorator in inherited `class TestSomething`. The reason why I use `decorator.decorator` is because of pytest fixtures, I need the decorator to call function with right signature. Basicly, pytest has to see `f(some_fixture)` and not `f(*args)` because `*args` is not any fixture.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly.  You want one or more decorators that collaborate to (1) produce a classmethod (2) decorate a function that does not accept a `cls` argument (3) decorate a function whose argument list can be analyzed, as with `inspect.getargspec`, and will not just accept varargs.

Comment: If all that is correct, I think your best bet is to use `getargspec` to get the argument list, build the source of
`wrapper` as a string (with the additional initial `cls` argument), use the `exec` statement to create the `wrapper` function, and return it.  All that would be done in your decorator.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I can't imagine that, Can you please show me simple example, based on the examples I provided in question? Or just edit it to your answer.